# how summing while reducing (alternating) in the array or repetition in PHP

Tags: php

for example:

$a = 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5 + 6

```
$result = 0;
for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++) {
   $result += $i;
}
```

way over just to add it. is there a way to run it alternating?

Answer (score 4):

Just add a multiplier that changes its sign every iteration:

```
$result = 1;
$sign = 1;

for($i=2; $i<=6; $i++) {
   $result += $i * $sign;
   $sign *= -1;
}
```

A note: I also changed the iteration to start with 2, since the 2 members are both start with positive sign: `+1` and `+2`

Comment: what if his position changed, such as:

$a = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5.. etc

Comment: @aon, $result = 0, $i = 1

Answer (score 0):

You could make a formula (using staring method) and avoid a loop.

For your example

```
// $a = 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5 + 6;
$n = 6;
echo ceil ($n / 2) * ($n % 2 ? -1 : 1) + 2; // 5
```

But if you need other sequence

```
// $a = 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6;
echo ceil ($n / 2) * ($n % 2 ? 1 : -1); // -3
```

But example was changed.

```
$values = [10, 45, 6, 11, 8];

// 1
$result = 0;
reset($values);
while (key($values) !== null)
    {
    $result += current($values) - next($values);
    next($values);
    }
var_dump($result);

// 2    
var_dump(
    array_sum(
        array_column(array_chunk($values, 2), 0)) - array_sum(array_column(array_chunk($values, 2), 1)));

// 3
var_dump(
    array_reduce(array_chunk($values, 2), function ($result, $item)
        {
        return $result + current($item) - next($item);
        }));

// 4
$result = 0;
$i = 1;
foreach ($values as $value)
    {
    $result += ($i++ % 2? : -1) * $value;
    }
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: what if my count is not a number that is sequential? for example:

$val = array(10, 45, 6, 11, 8);

desired $a = 10 - 45 + 6 - 11 + 8

Comment: @aon, ok, i have added some examples for you.